# Is there a visual component for write a number directly through PBI in published report?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I would like to allow users to input a integer number to be used in some calculations.

I know that it is possible to use What-if parameters. However, What-if parameters can only be used with value ranges between 0 and 1,000. For the ranges greater than 1,000, the parameter value will be sampled.

For example, I can't write 8,529 because the number will be sampled to 8,521.

Maybe there is some hidden workaround or a custom visual component. I tested with Smart Filter by OKVIZ but it doesn't work in Power BI Service neither in an embedded application.

Thanks a lot!

--- Miguel-Angel

Answer (score 0):

I used the Smart Filter Pro and it works.